# Conditional expectation of symmetric random walk

Tags: probability

Question: We have a symmetric random walk on the integers starting at n=1. Let L be the first time the walk first hits 0. Let A be the event that the walk hits 0 before it hits 3. What is E(L|A)?

I am really not sure how to deal with this conditional expectation or how to even start this question. I have tried to use the definition of conditional expectation but I just haven't gotten anywhere. I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious so I'd appreciate any hints.

Comment: Hint: while calculating the conditional probability, you should consider only those walks that don't reach 3. You can just say that the integers end at 2 (you can't walk past that) and calculate simple probability $E(L)$ in this model.

Comment: Is this even well defined? $E[|L|]$ is infinite, I believe the conditional expectation is defined only if the expectation itself is finite?

Comment: @VasiliiIugov Thanks for the hint! Just to check in our new model the walk is no longer symmetric right? So when we are at n= 1, the probability to go down to 0 is 3/4 and to go up 2 is 1/4, and when we are at 2 the probability to go down to 1 is 1. If what I just wrote is correct, then I get my answer as E(L|A) = 5/3

Comment: @minus123 If the walk is symmetric then at $n=1$ the probabilities to go up and down should be $1/2$ and at $n=2$ the probability to go down is $1$.

Comment: @VasiliiIugov But doesn't the condition of the walk hitting 0 before 3 affect the probability that the first move is to 0? Without the condition the probability is 1/2, since the walk is symmetric, but when you condition on the fact that it hits 0 before hitting 3 surely the probability that the very first move is from 1 to 0 is greater than 1/2? Sorry if I've explained poorly but I was under the impression that conditioning on A increases the probability that our very first move was to the left.

Comment: The way to understand conditional probabilities is to consider the ratio of probabilities of two random walks that satisfy the condition $A$. This ratio should be the same as in the model without the condition $A$. Thus, when you are at position $1$, you have the same probability to go right and to go left no matter the conditioning. On the other hand, when you are at position $2$, you have only one choice. Thus, its conditional probability is equal to 1.

Comment: Ok I think I understand. Thank you for the help!